# Using commands to find blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My memory is vague on this one, but I do remember a command that could identify where particular things are - like wolves, or End Ships/Forts. I don't remember the command to do it, but I do remember that it could be done in chat; no Command blocks required.

Can this be done to find blocks? For example, the new Amethyst blocks?

Answer (score 2):

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/locate

`/locate <StructureType>`
You can use the auto-complete to see what structures you can teleport to. The new 1.17 geodes should be on the list.

EDIT: It seems that the new 1.17 geodes are not on the list.

Comment: Please note that in Java edition, the `StructureType` argument is case-sensitive.